# Publish RTMP Stream from Flash player or Applet to wowza media server

Tags: java, rtmp, live-streaming, wowza

> Hi,
>
> I am working on streaming application where i need to publish my video
>   to wowza media server.  **My requirement is "Any person who want to give
>   speech, stand in front of webcam which is shown on window on browser
>   or desktop then this video is streamed to wowza and then at last wowza
>   will broadcast this stream to multiple devices".**
>
> I can't understand from where i have to start. I need some tutorials
>   or documents which give me knowledge about live streaming. Because i
>   have to start from bottom, so searched bit but most of links showing
>   me software.
>
> So it is helpful to me if i get any material by which i publish my
>   stream to wowza media server.
>
> Thank You.

Comment: Hi Aniket, could you figure out something useful?